# Is there a way to combine websockets and normal http through apache?

Tags: apache, websocket

So I have this server where I host more than one website for professional purposes. But I also like to develop game websites and I would like to create a roguelike game with HTML5.

The game engine itself would be developped in C++ on the server and the client should ask the server what changes in the environment after every move.

So, normally, I would send an ajax request to the server where apache would reroute the request to my C++ application which is running as a FastCGI Service. My C++ application would check the session, look up if the movement is valid, change the internal values so that the character moves, also changes other things in the environment, and would then send the changes back to the client.

But ajax requests can be relatively slow, opening and closing connections all the time. So when I read about websockets, I thought I was in heaven until I saw that it will interfere with Apache and Apache is not really optimized to work with it.

Obviously, I could create a web socket on a different port, but with all those firewalls out there, I don't think that's a good option.

So, is there a way to combine the two? Where apache is able to understand that a websocket request should be ignored and passed on to my application instead?

Comment: Why do you need to have Apache there at all? You can just connect to your application directly.

Comment: Like I said in the first sentence: I host more than one website for professional purposes. They are pure html and/or php and I need something that routes the domains to the right directories, like Apache does.

Comment: That doesn't mean you need Apache for websockets.

Comment: Ah, but that's why I ask the above question. I need the websockets to run on the same port 80 and when I try to do that, my application tells me that port 80 is in use. So, how can I solve that?